# Storing data from text into variables

Tags: java, text-files

I'm trying to read data from a text file and store various data types into variables.
Assuming the txt file is in the following form;

a 1000 1
   b 2000 2
   c 3000 3

Now, I'm trying to store the characters into separate variables and the integers into separate variables.

My attempt so far has involved me reading the text file into a string and then using string tokenizer to store each element into an array list. I kind of have a general idea on how to go about doing this; check to see if the element in the list is a character, if so, store it into a character variable or else if its an integer, store it into an int.
 However, I am not familiar with the methods on identifying whether something is a string or an integer, like isString, isInteger, etc etc. Could anyone please give me some advice on how to go about doing this?

My code as follows:

```
public class copyToString {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileSpecified = args[0];

        fileSpecified = fileSpecified.concat(".txt");
        char [] content = new char[1024];

        System.out.println ("file Specified = " + fileSpecified);

        String container;
        ArrayList <String> words = new ArrayList<String> ();


        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader (fileSpecified);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            int read = 0;
            while ((read = br.read(content, 0, content.length)) > 0) {
                builder.append(content, 0, read);
            }

            container = builder.toString();

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer (container);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                words.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
            }
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println (e.getMessage());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println ("words = " + words.get(i));


        }



    }



}
```

Thanks

Comment: you could use Scanner - it's really simpler than StringTokenizer. One thing is not clear. You're saying that the input file format is known and giving the sample, so why do you want to recognize variable type programatically?

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, Scanner is in fact easier, it'll save me the time too. The input file format I have given is just one sample out of many that we have been provided for a task. I have to consider characters and integers separately since I will be dealing with them in different ways. Is this answer what you might've expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't know what each type might be, you have to store every field as String as a number like `1000` could be a short, int, long, float, double or String. Is `1` a number , String or the character '1'?  Without context you cannot know what each type is. `a`, `b` and `c` could be a numbers in hexidecimal. ;)

---

It would take me longer to say what I would do differently, than it would to re-write the code. ;)

```
public class CopyToString {
    static class Line {
        String word;
        int num1, num2;

        Line(String word, int num1, int num2) {
            this.word = word;
            this.num1 = num1;
            this.num2 = num2;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Line{" + "word='" + word + '\'' + ", num1=" + num1 + ", num2=" + num2 + '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        String fileSpecified = args[0] + ".txt";
        System.out.println("file Specified = " + fileSpecified);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileSpecified));

        List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
            lines.add(new Line(scanner.next(), scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt()));
        }
        br.close();

        for (Line l : lines)
            System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

prints

```
file Specified = text.txt
Line{word='a', num1=1000, num2=1}
Line{word='b', num1=2000, num2=2}
Line{word='c', num1=3000, num2=3}
```

Comment: Thankyou. If say, the txt file contained an unknown length of data (considering the amount of data in the txt file will vary), we would have to declare quite a lot of variables. Now, in-order to avoid doing this, is it possible to declare a char array of a moderate size and then store the characters in it and an int array and do the same thing?

Comment: If you can assume you only have char or int, you can use a plain int[] (as char fits inside an int) In that case I would use split and parseInt.  How will you tell the differences between the number 1 and the character '1'

Comment: The txt files that we have given will always be in that same format that I have shown. In that case, every line has an alphabet (char) to start with and then have an int(e.g: 1000) and an unsigned int (e.g: 1). In that case, do I really have to worry about differentiating between a number 1 and a character '1'?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the Apache Commons Lib here very much. Because this lib has a

- StringUtils class which has a large method base for checking the content of string
- IOUtils class for reading files easily

Additionally I would use simple regular expression groups to identify your text parts.

See Pattern and Matcher class for details. (Regex for Words: "\w" Digits "\d")